# How to set environment for Blackberry Phonegap?

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I tried with the procedure in http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Blackberry but i cant set apache ant please help me to set environment. and guide to to develop the application

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Install the WebWorks SDK
2. Install Ant and set environment variable path of bin folder. 
   Link:http://ant.apache.org/bindownload.cgi
3. Register for Signing Keys 
   Link:https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/signing_setup_smartphone_apps_1920010_11.html

   3.1 Paste signing keys to C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5\bin
   3.2 Install all key from command prompt with command (java -jar SignatureTool.jar [CSI file name].csi) from bin folder.
4. Build Project from project folder with command (ant blackberry build).
5. Run Project from project folder with command (ant blackberry load-simulator).

Comment: Follow the step and let me know what problem you faced