# how to set a phonegap environment for blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, cordova

I am not able to set the environment of phonegap for blackberry. The process given in docs.phonegap.com is not so clear and I am having problems in setting the environment and creating a new App.

Answer (score 1):

Hi Sumit be specific with your question,what you want to know regarding blackberry environment.

Have you had a look into the following documentations.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html

[How to set environment for Blackberry Phonegap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649537/how-to-set-environment-for-blackberry-phonegap)

http://www.horochovec.com/blackberry-apache-cordova-phonegap/

Hope this helps to get you started.